# Why do I call socket.write function continuously but only trigger IPC Server 'data' event once in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ipc, nodejs-stream

I created an IPC server, I will send message to the client during the entire program life cycle. When the client receives the message, it will process it, but will not send the message to the server.

```
// Server.js
let server = net.createServer(socket=> {
    socket.setEncoding('utf-8');
    socket.on('close', onClientDisconnectOrProcessExit);
    socket.on('error', err => {});
    socket.on("data", data => {});

    // Call four times continuously
    socket.write("hello 1");
    socket.write("hello 2");
    socket.write("hello 3");
    socket.write("hello 4");

}).listen({path: FIFO_NAME});
```

```
// Client.js
let socket = new net.Socket();
socket.setEncoding('utf-8');
socket.connect(FIFO_NAME, () => {});
socket.on('data', data => {
    // Why only trigger once here ?
    console.log(data);
});
```

When I try other solutions, add cork() and unsork() around but got same result:

```
socket.cork();
socket.write("hello 1");
socket.uncork();
socket.cork();
socket.write("hello 2");
socket.uncork();
socket.cork();
socket.write("hello 3");
socket.uncork();
socket.cork();
socket.write("hello 4");
socket.uncork();
```

Why it's os ?

Comment: Client.js log show:
`hello 1hello 2hello 3hello 4`

this log show in event the only once

Comment: Seems to be merged into one